# FineUI Mvc empty project on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Anyone has experience with FineUI UI component? I downloaded the Mvc trial package and deployed their included EmptyProject to windows Azure as an App Service, but got the following error:

**The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.**

The App service URL looks like 
http://mytestapp.azurewebsites.net/

There is no any details to explain this error. I even tried to set customErrors to off, but Azure didn't return more info regarding the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error from Azure are resulting from below two configurations

1. Managed Pipeline Mode
   FineUIMvc.EmptyProject is using Classic mode, we need change to Integrated as Azure App Settings is using Integrated mode by default.
2. targetFramework version
   FineUIMvc.EmptyProject is using 4.5 by default, so you need change its version to 4.7 in Web.config to match Azure App settings. Azure provides 3.5 and 4.7 but not 4.5.

We provide the following steps to fix this:

1. On Azure, (SETTINGS -> Application settings -> General settings),  update .NET Framework version to 4.7, and set Managed Pipeline Mode to Integrated if not.  (see Azure App Settings.png file)
2. In project Web.config, comment out system.web httpModules and httpHandlers, instead add  for modules and handlers  (see http://mvc.fineui.us/#/Config/ModifyWebConfig)
3. Update targetFramework to 4.7
4. Change project Managed Pipeline Mode to Integrated
5. Republish the project updates to Azure and try again

We also created a testing service https://fineuitest.azurewebsites.net/ for your reference.

Of course, you can also keep Classic mode, but change targetFramework to 4.7 in Web.confg and change App Settings to Classic mode.

Hope above explanation helps.